# How to add auto-update feature for WordPress plugin or theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add the auto-update feature to theme or plugins that I publish separately from the WordPress repository. Thanks if anyone can help.
I searched Google several times but did not find any results.
I think we need to write a script and put the updates in it and get the plugin updates from it.

Comment: See https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/30/recommended-usage-of-the-updates-api-to-support-the-auto-updates-ui-for-plugins-and-themes-in-wordpress-5-5/, https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/self-hosted-plugin-update.html, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/62159/12496

Comment: I have never seen that. Why not tp use the WordPress plugin/theme repository?